# How to override the CSS classes into a Liferay SearchContainer?

Tags: css, jsp, liferay, portlet

Working on a Liferay 6.2 portlet that displays a search container into a JSP page. Is it possible to override the SearchContainer CSS classes?

I set a simple CSS class:

```
.green_background {
    background-color: #7AF20A;
}
```

I tried to apply it on a SearchContainer column:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text  property="incFg_isClosed" name="Type" cssClass="span1 green_background "  orderable="true" orderableProperty="incFg_isClosed" />
```

And it does not override the search container classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Css reference by the top css class `aui` , otherwise it will be overrided, check [liferay-documentation](https://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/alloyui-2-0-bootstrap-migration-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en)

```
.aui .green_background {
    background-color: #7AF20A;
     }
```

Comment: @AD  can you inspect your browser and tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: : I tested with Chrome Developpers tools and with Firefox console. I ot no particular error in relation with this...

Comment: @AD I meant to check if the property was applied to the desired field or got overrided, I don't know about the behaviour you are expecting

Comment: as the  background-color: #7AF20A does not apply, I take it that the SearchContainer classes still override my class?

Comment: @AD `search-container-column-text` is the text label, apply the css to a higher level like `search-container` to see if it works .

Comment: I want to apply it only on this column (IE : if the variable = true, I display in green, if it's false I ll display in red with another class).

Comment: check the generated html from `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text..>` and specify yur target for example `.aui .search-container table tr {...} ` this will target lines if you want a specif column add a td specification to your css

Answer (score 0):

Be care about css cascading rules and preset bootstrap/liferay styles.
Use the more precise css rule.

```
.aui .table-striped tbody>tr>td.green_background {
    background-color: #7AF20A;
}
```